# Almost complex structures on $\mathbb CP^2$ that are not tamed

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Recall that an almost complex structure $J$ on a manifold $M^{2n}$ is called *tamed* if there exists a symplectic form $\omega$ on $M^{2n}$ such that $\omega(v,Jv)>0$ for any non-zero tangent vector $v$.

**Question.** Is there an example of an almost complex structure on $\mathbb CP^2$ such that any $C^{\infty}$ small perturbation of $J$ is not tamed?

**Added.** It turns out that there exists as well a purely *local* obstruction for any small perturbations of $J$ to be tamed. The precise statement and the answer is here:    [Almost complex structures on a 4-ball that are not tamed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263500/almost-complex-structures-on-a-4-ball-that-are-not-tamed)

Comment: Start with a $J$ which admits a null-homologous $J$-holomorphic sphere $C$. This can always be achieved by deforming a given almost complex structure in a small neighborhood of a point. Then $J$ cannot be tamed, and furthermore $C$ should persist as a null-homologous $J'$-holomorphic sphere (i.e. it should deform) for any small perturbation $J'$ of $J$. This is because the linearized operator is surjective since it satisfies the numerical inequality $c_1(\nu)=0\geq -1$ ($\nu$ normal bundle of $C$) needed to apply $2.1.C_1$ in Gromov's paper, see also Hofer-Lizan-Sikorav.

Comment: I think that $c_1(v)=-2$, so this argument does not work. Indeed, since $C$ is null-homologous, $c_1(\mathbb CP^2)$ restricts to $C$ as zero, on the other hand $c_1(TC)=2$, since $C$ is a sphere.

Comment: yes, you are right, sorry.

Comment: The strategy of YangMills is still a good one. But instead, you should take a J such that a _smoothly_knotted_ sphere of degree one becomes J-holomorphic. Tameness would imply that the standard CP^2 has a smoothly knotted symplectic embedding of degree one, which is in contradiction with a result by Gromov.

Comment: Great! Would you mind to put this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarising the discussion above and Daniel Ruberman's helpful clarifications below.

Any symplectic structure on $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is standard by a result due to Gromov and Taubes. By Siebert-Tian every symplectic surface in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ of degree at most 17 is smoothly isotopic to an algebraic surface. In particular, there is a unique smooth isotopy class of such surfaces.

Now, take $S \subset \mathbb{C}P^2$ a surface of low degree which is not ambient diffeomorphic to an algebraic surface, but which satisfies the adjunction formula ($g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$). Any almost complex structure  for which $S$ is pseudoholomorphic can then *not* be tamed. (To see that such an almost complex structure exists in the right homotopy class, we can find a smooth homtopy of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ from the identity to a smooth map (not a diffeomorphisms obviously!) which sends $S$ to an algebraic surface.)

Finally, by the automatic transversality of Hofer-Lizan-Sikorav, for a small perturbation of the almost complex structure we can find a pseudoholomorphic surface isotopic to $S$; these almost complex structures hence do not admit taming forms either. (In order to apply the automatic transversality, we must use the assumptions that $c_1([S]) \ge 1$ and that $S$ is immersed.)

Comment: But a sphere S whose self-intersection is $+1$ has simply connected complement!  If you take a pushoff $S'$ that hits S in one point (as you can) then $S'$ minus a meridional disk is another disk that provides a null-homotopy for the meridian. A well-known conjecture in 4-manifold topology (see Kirby's problem list, Problem 4.23) states that any 2-sphere in the standard homology class in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is isotopic to  $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

Comment: Oh, you're right of course. I wanted to say something more precise than just "knotted", but I obviously screwed up.

Comment: I should point out that having a simply connected complement implies that the sphere S is topologically isotopic to $\mathbb{C}P^1$. The conjecture I cited is really asking about the smooth situation. Also, there are knotted surfaces in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ of higher degrees, so perhaps you could repeat the argument starting with one of these.

Comment: Ok, thanks for straightening out the situation. If there are smoothly knotted surfaces of degree at most 17 then the argument can be modified to work. Are there such examples? :)

Comment: Yes. First off, there are topologically knotted surfaces in all degrees greater than one; you just connect sum the standard algebraic curve with the spun knot (in $S^4$) of a non-trivial knot in the 3-sphere. This always changes the fundamental group; this follows from the solution of the Smith conjecture for knots in the 3-sphere.  If you want smoothly knotted surfaces that are topologically unknotted, these exist in degrees at least 3, by work of Hee Jung Kim ($d \geq 3$) and Sergey Finashin ($d \geq 5$). I assume you are making use of the Siebert-Tian result to make this statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It sounds convincing. Just to make sure, the expected (real) dimension of the moduli space of degree $d$ curves for any $J$ on $\mathbb CP^2$ is $d(d+3)$? So, if you have a curve as you say, it will survive (as a J-holomorphic curve) after a small perturbation of $J$?

Comment: Exactly, that's what the automatic transversality gives you (which can be applied since the index is positive, as you said).

Comment: In fact, I realized that I don't have enough knowledge to understand what should be used to prove that when one perturbs $J$ the curve does not disappear. Could you please add a reference? What's automatic transversality? Indeed, if we take a projective K3, a genus $g$ curve varies in a family of complex dimension $g$, while the expected real dimension is $2g$ (according to http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Pseudoholomorphic_curves). On the other hand, you can  take a small non-algebraic deformation and all curves on K3 will disappear. What prevents this to happen in the case you describe?

Comment: In that situation the Chern class vanishes on the surface, so the automatic transversality theorem cannot be applied. (We need an immersed surface, and we need its normal bundle times the anticanonical bundle to be positive.)

Comment: In fact, it is a very nice construction. I wonder if it is new, in the sense - was is written down anywhere explicitly that the space of tamed almost complex structures on $\mathbb CP^2$ is not dense inside the space of all almost complex structures. (I was thinking it should be known, maybe even for some local reasons -- i.e. from some example inside of a ball, but I was not able to find a reference).

Comment: I'm not aware of any references. If one could construct knotted surfaces which are _diffeomorphic_ but not isotopic to algebraic ones, then it would be possible to use a similar method to show nonconnectedness of the subset. Does someone know if such examples exist? (I would guess that we don't know the answer.)