# Almost complex structures on a 4-ball that are not tamed

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry, h-principle

Recall that an almost complex structure $J$ on a manifold $M^{2n}$ is called *tamed* if there exists a symplectic form $\omega$ on $M^{2n}$ such that $\omega(v,Jv)>0$ for any non-zero tangent vector $v$.

**Question.** Is there an almost complex structure $J$ on a closed ball $B^4$, such that any $C^{\infty}$-small perturbation of $J$ is not tamed by any symplectic form? (I assume that $J$ behaves nicely on the boundary of $B^4$, in particular it is smooth there).

*Remark.* Clearly, if such $J$ exists on $B^4$, it would exists on any $4$-manifold admitting an almost complex structure.

This question is a follow-up to the following one, where a global obstruction for "tamebility" was found for $\mathbb CP^2$
[Almost complex structures on $\mathbb CP^2$ that are not tamed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262300/almost-complex-structures-on-mathbb-cp2-that-are-not-tamed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following construction provides plenty of examples of non-tamed almost complex structures:

Consider an almost complex structure $J$ on $B^4$ for which the contact hyperplanes of the *overtwisted* contact structure on $S^3=\partial B^4$ (in the same homotopy class as the standard tight contact structure) become $J$-complex. If there was a taming symplectic form, we would have constructed a so-called weak symplectic filling of an overtwisted contact manifold. However, This is not possible by a result of Eliashberg and Gromov.

Finally, observe that the contact condition is open, and by Gray's stability also a perturbation of $J$ would be tangent to $\partial B^4$ along some tangent hyperplane distribution being an *overtwisted* contact structure.

Comment: What are you using to construct such a $J$? Certainly if such a $J$ exists it satisfies the conditions of the question, but I don't see where the construction is coming from.

Comment: Since I am assuming that the contact structure is homotopic to the standard contact structure on $S^3$, the almost complex structure can be taken to be homotopic to the standard integrable complex structure on the ball (we just need to deform the complex tangencies along the boundary).

Comment: In the definition of weak filling one asks that $\omega$ is convex at the boundary. How do you see that any $\omega$ taming $J$ has to be convex at $S^3$?

Comment: The contact condition means that the exterior differential of any contact form (which in this case is equal to the Levi form of $J$) is nondegenerate on the contact planes.

Comment: @aglearner Typically a weak symplectic filling is defined so that $\omega$ restricted the contact planes is $>0$ (in the sense that it is non-degenerate on the contact planes and agrees with their preferred orientation), but this is completely equivalent to the taming condition as the contact planes are complex.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I see that weak symplectic filling does not require the boundary to be convex, (indeed, this is definition 2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3923.pdf).  I'll accept the answer, may I just ask you to include the definition of weak symplectic filling in the answer? (it is not immediate to find it in the internet)

Comment: @aglearner There is also an argument of Eliashberg which shows given that the form is zero in cohomology, that any weak filling of a contact structure can be modified to a strong filling of the same contact structure. This is a short and straightforward argument in the "A few remarks..." paper (prop 4.1 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311459.pdf).